# run same command on ssh terminal vs ubuntu desktop, on ssh termial can not runing?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ssh

I have a ubuntu destop. I login in by root and `cd /snap/bin/anbox`, it can start app. Like this [image]

But when I run same commend on ssh terminal on my local macbook, it can not start app. 
[image]
Maybe tty reason, can i set special tty?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you try to start a GUI program, with a console. If you want to start the app you need Xorg/X11. Search for X11 forwarding.